# Cannot upgrade to syncElegantOTA v3 in platformIO

Tags: upgrade, esp32, ota, platformio

In my ESP32 project I want to use asyncElegantOTA. As development enviornment I am using Visual Studio Code (v1.87.2) with platformIO (v3.3.3). When compiling my project I am getting the following warning:

AsyncElegantOTA library is deprecated, Please consider moving to newer ElegantOTA library which now comes with an Async Mode. Learn More: https://docs.elegantota.pro/async-mode/

The current installed version is 2.2.8.

In my platformio.ini file, I have this line inside the lib_deps:
ayushsharma82/AsyncElegantOTA @ ^2.2.8

I followed the link, mentioned in the warning which brings you to the following documentation:

> If you use PlatformIO then we can use a neat trick! You can set build_flags in your platformio.ini file that enables Async Mode of ElegantOTA.
>
> Open platformio.ini file of your project
> Paste this line build_flags=-DELEGANTOTA_USE_ASYNC_WEBSERVER=1 at bottom
> Done!
> PlatformIO will now compile ElegantOTA in Async Mode!

However, not sure, if it really compiles ElegantOTA in Async Mode, but the problem with the deprecated version is not solved.

I searched the libraries but the highes version which is offered is that I already have.

What else I can try to upgrade to AsyncElegantOTA v3 in platformIO? Or, is my expectation wrong that this upgrade should be possible (despite the warning)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `platformio.ini` file of your project

Add

`lib_deps = https://github.com/ayushsharma82/ElegantOTA.git`

You will get the latest version.

Comment: This does unfortunatelly not work. Not sure how the proposed library is related to AsyncElegantOTA v3?